# For an arbitrary Ising model, is there any numerical method to calculate its free energy with polynomial cost?

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, computational-physics, ising-model

Specifically: calculate the expression:

$$
\sum_{s_i=\pm 1}exp(A_{ij}s_is_j)
$$

Where index $i = 1 \sim M$, and $A_{ij}$ is an arbitrary real symmetric matrix.
I am trying to find a method with polynomial cost, i.e $O(M^n)$. And should involve no stochastic method, like Monte Carlo. Which means I'd like the method to be precise

Answer (score 1):

It has been shown that finding the free energy, or equivalently, the partition function, of an arbitrary Ising model is an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem.
For instance, "On the computational complexity of Ising spin glass models", F. Barahona, J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 15 (1982) proves this via a mapping onto the "Cocycle of maximum cardinality in a cubic graph" problem.

So the answer is no, so far no strategy has been found that works for an arbitrary matrix $A$.